# Google Map Marker wrongly change position while drag drop

Tags: c#, dictionary, drag-and-drop, xamarin

I know we have some similar questions already but all of them can not help me solve my issue (because of the difference platform). So I put my question here with a hope that someone can help me.

I am working on a xamarin project and using Google Map API ver 2 to make a map.
When I touch on the map, I will add a new marker by using this code.

```
public void AddPoint(LatLng pointPossition)
    {
        MarkerOptions markerPoint = new MarkerOptions();

        markerPoint.Anchor (0.5f, 1.0f);//The same issue occur when I remove this line
        markerPoint.InvokeIcon(m_PointMoveableIcon);
        markerPoint.SetPosition (pointPossition);
        markerPoint.Draggable (true);

        Marker marker = m_Map.AddMarker(markerPoint);//m_Map is the Google Map
        m_Markers.Add(marker);//m_Markers is a list to store all created markers
    }
```

By that way, I can create some makers on the map
[image]

All markers are draggable, so I can long click on any marker and drag it to another position, but unfortunately, the dragged marker change position suddenly, and this behavior is really bad.

[image]

I tried many solutions but not work. So, I hope someone can help me.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Does the offset change when you modify the `anchor`?

Comment: The same issue occur when I remove the line "markerPoint.Anchor (0.5f, 1.0f);"

Answer (score 1):

I had this quest now. And it's my solution is code below.
Why first number is it, i don't know, but it's works for my debugger. And 0.5 probably is half marker position.

```
private void Map_PinDragging(object sender, PinDragEventArgs e)
{
    int m = map.Pins.IndexOf(e.Pin);
    map.Pins.ElementAt(m).Position = new Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Position(e.Pin.Position.Latitude - (0.001347153801 * 0.5), e.Pin.Position.Longitude);
}

private void Map_PinDragStart(object sender, PinDragEventArgs e)
{
    int m = map.Pins.IndexOf(e.Pin);
    map.Pins.ElementAt(m).Position = new Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Position(e.Pin.Position.Latitude - (0.001347153801 * 0.5), e.Pin.Position.Longitude);
}
Pin DragPin;
private void Map_PinDragEnd(object sender, PinDragEventArgs e)
{
    int m = map.Pins.IndexOf(e.Pin);
    map.Pins.ElementAt(m).Position = new Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Position(e.Pin.Position.Latitude - (0.001347153801*0.5), e.Pin.Position.Longitude);
}
```

And...
This value change with my map Zoom. Needs some math there.